# Creating Model relation in ASP.NET MVC 5 in VB

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm creating two simple models "**MusicStyle**" and "**Bands**", and i want a **Band** to have a **MusicStyle**. All the examples i can find are in C# and i can't figure out how is the correct syntax in Visual Basic.

Here is my code for both Classes/Models.

```
Public Class MusicStyle
    Public Property MusicStyleID() As Integer
    Public Property MusicStyleName() As String
End Class
```

```
Public Class Bands
    Public Property BandsID() As Integer
    Public Property BandsName() As String
    Public Overridable Property MusicStyleID() As ICollection(Of MusicStyle)
End Class
```

For some reason this generates an FK in the **MusicStyle** Table instead **Bands** table, and no HTML controls in the Views for the FK.

[Tables and Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LurkT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code in order to accomplish the right relationship:

```
Public Class Band
   Public Property BandID() As Integer
   Public Property BandName() As String
   'This is the FK
   Public Property MusicStyleID() As Integer
   <ForeignKey("MusicStyleID")> 
   Public Property MusicStyleRef() As MusicStyle
End Class

Public Class MusicStyle
   Public Property MusicStyleID() As Integer
   Public Property MusicStyleName() As String
   Public Overridable Property Bands() As ICollection(Of Band)
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hackerman!, this also works refactoring only **Bands** class. But i dont know if this way misses something important you did in your code.

```
Public Class Band
   Public Property BandID() As Integer
   Public Property BandName() As String
   Public Property MusicStyleID() As Integer
   Public Property MusicStyleRef() As MusicStyle
End Class

Public Class MusicStyle
   Public Property MusicStyleID() As Integer
   Public Property MusicStyleName() As String
End Class
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think that this not reflects the scenario properly...basically in my answer you define the relation `One Band haves a Music Style` and `One Music Style can be shared by multiple Bands`...in that way it's more legible-readable because reflect the relationship in both ways.